# Change PHP compilation

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp

I tried installing V8JS on my xampp server but an error occurred. I searched but did not find the extension version in VC11

```
Warning: PHP Startup: v8js: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20131226,TS,VC12
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20131226,TS,VC11
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

How do I make my PHP compile into VC12?

My current settings

```
System  Windows NT DESKTOP-HPGI9H9 6.2 build 9200 (Windows 8 Home Premium Edition) i586
Build Date  Oct 29 2015 12:34:05
Compiler    MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012)
Architecture    x86
Apache Version  Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.15
XAMPP v3.2.2
```

Comment: What PHP version is that? The latest releases from PHP are compiled using VC14 and VC15 however I am not sure in how to compile PHP in Windows, never did it before :|

Comment: My current version is PHP / 5.6.15

Comment: Well 5.6 is not being actively develop so I guess they will not release any more builds unless it is a fix for a security issue, check [here](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php). As for compile in Windows I don't think you would be able to use CV12 (see [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.requirements.php)) since they said it requires VC11

Comment: I can not understand if 5.6 can not be compiled in VC12 because there is php_v8js for 5.6 VC12

Answer (score 0):

This solves the problem. It is only substituting the Xampp files for these:
https://github.com/maryo/php-5.6.13-win32-VC12